# ViewBag select list LINQ table join

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

Is it possible to join tables in a SelectList?

Here is what I have:

```
ViewBag.Clients = new SelectList(db.IPACS_Clients, "clientID", "name", 0);
```

I need to join the db.IPACS_Clients_Network table, I still need "clientID" but for "name" I need to be able to select IPACS_Clients.name + " - " + IPACS_Clients_Network.name

Is this possible with a Viewbag?

Comment: You probably need to join the necessary tables in a Linq statement first, and pass the result to the SelectList constructor.

Comment: I would suggest creating a model that has all the properties you need per selectlist item and use a join to populate these models. I would also suggest you create a 'main'-model for the view itself which has a property called `ClientCollection` and assign your selectlist to that.

Comment: @Silvermind: Why all that ceremony?  Normally I would just put the SelectList on the ViewModel directly as a member.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thats what I meant, but perhaps not clear enough. The result would be something on the View like `Model.ClientCollection` which would be a `SelectList`, but perhaps `Model.ClientDataSelectList` would describe it better.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was able to figure it out.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Silvermind I understand what should be done, however my request wasn't how to set up separate models etc.  I've posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this way is not recommended, I was able to find the answer.

```
ViewBag.Clients = new SelectList(db.IPACS_Clients_Network
       .Join(
          db.IPACS_Clients,
          v => v.networkClientID,
          s => s.networkClientID,
          (v, s) =>
             new
             {
                 v = v,
                 s = s
             }
       )
       .Select(
          temp0 =>
             new
             {
                 v = temp0.v,
                 s = temp0.s
             }
       ).Select(m => new SelectListItem
       {
           Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)m.s.clientID).Trim(),
           Text = m.v.name + " - " + m.s.name
       }), "Value", "Text", 0);
```